# Need to find a unique solution of the series

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, polynomials

I have a series

$\eqalign{\gamma &= \sum_{m=1}^\infty (-1)^m \frac{C_1^{mk-m+1} C_3^m}{C_4^{mk+1} m!} \prod_{j=0}^{m-2} (mk-j) \cr
&= \frac{C_1}{C_4} - \frac{C_1^k C_3}{C_4^{k+1}} + \frac{2k\; C_1^{2k-1} C_3^2}{2!\; C_4^{2k+1}} - \frac{3k(3k-1)\; C_1^{3k-2} C_3^{3}}{3!\; C_4^{3k+1}} + \frac{4k(4k-1)(4k-2)\; C_1^{4k-3} C_3^4}{4!\; C_4^{4k+1}} + \ldots }$

also, the convergence condition:

$\left| \frac{C_1^{k-1} C_3}{C_4^k} \right| < \frac{(k-1)^{k-1}}{k^k}$

is satisfied. I also have $C_1, C_3, C_4 > 0$ and $C_1 < C_3 + C_4$ satisfied.

I need to find the value of $\gamma$ in the interval $(0,1)$.

Comment: If the series converges, take sufficiently many terms and you have a good approximation to the sum.

Comment: Thank you very much! I finally obtained the required result. Fortunately, the series converged at the very first term for $\gamma\in(0,1)$ , with the obtained values of the constants.